# Web Scraping between tags

Tags: regex, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to get all of the content between  tags from a webpage.  The code I have is outputting empty arrays. When I print the htmltext it shows the complete contents of the page, but will not show the contents of the tags.

```
 import urllib
 import re

 urlToOpen = "webAddress"
 htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urlToOpen)
 htmltext = htmlfile.read()
 regex = '<h5> (.*)  </h5>'
 pattern = re.compile(regex)
 names = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
 print "The h5 tag contains: ", names
```

Comment: Two notices: 1) regex is not the good tool parse html use beautifulsoup instead. 2) in a regex pattern whitespaces are significant.

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake while calling the string urlToOpen. Write `str(urlToOpen)` instead of urlToOpen.

```
import urllib2
import re

urlToOpen = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107611/web-scraping-between-tags"
htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(str(urlToOpen))
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
names = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print names
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont give spaces between tags and regex expression. Write like this:

```
regex = '<h5>(.+?)</h5>'
```